# Don't understand variables

Tags: go, variables

I'm confused with variables.
Case 1:

```
package main
var a = "F"
func main() {
  n()
  m()
  n()
}
func n() {
    print(a)
}
func m() {
  a = "O"
  print(a)
}
```

result = FOO

But when I change `a = "O"` on (`var a = "O"` or `a := "O"`) result is FOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var a = "O"` and `a := "O"` both declares new variables. That means the `a` inside `m` is a different `a` then the global variable, so setting it to `O` doesn't change the value of the global one.

You are allowed to shadow variables like this if they are in different scopes, which they are in this case.

One is in the global scope, and one is in the scope of `m` function.